# Notepad++ Change List in the format "Firstname Lastname" to "Firstname.Lastname@ourdomain.com;"

Tags: text, replace, notepad++, reformat

So I regularly get lists of names and need to be changing them into email addresses. They arrive like,

Firstname1 Lastname1

Firstname2 Lastname2
...and so on.

How can I use Notepad++ to change them into this?

Firstname1.Lastname1@ourdomain.com;

Firstname2.Lastname2@ourdomain.com;
...and so on?

I've never studied regular expressions but I suppose there must be a way of doing this fairly simply. I've searched on Google but nobody seems to have asked this precise question before. Also - it needs to retain the CRLF at the ends of the lines...

Comment: I don't know Notepad++, but for matching exactly 2 words per line, a `(\w+) (\w+)` can do the job, see https://regex101.com/r/DTEK8z/1 - however personally I'd just replace every single space with a dot in that file as a separate step (no regex involved), then it becomes a match-everything `(.*)`, and it won't matter any more how many names a person may have, https://regex101.com/r/50fDk6/2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text file has no lines with 2 or more spaces, you could use this:

Press <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> to open the Find/Replace popup, and then:

Find what:  `(.+)` (note the space at the start!)
      Replace with: `.\1@ourdomain.com`

Search mode:

⦿ Regular expression   ▢ `.` matches newline

Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

### Explanation

- : the space matches a literal space
- `.+`: requires at least one more character after that space, and captures all remaining characters until the end of the same line (In practice this is the *last name*).
- `()`: the parentheses make it possible to make reference to the captured group with `\1`

In the replace box, all characters are literal, except for `\1` as explained above. Note that the *first name* is not captured, as nothing needs to be replaced there.